# Instantons and confinement

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, instantons, confinement

Do instantons tell us something about behavior of QCD when lowering an energies? I.e., is it possible that instantons provide confinement? Are there some calculations which tell us that instantons corresponds to the interaction energy between strongly interacting particle which grows with distances?

Comment: This question is a bit vague - yes, instantons tell us "something" about confinement, because confinement is probably a phase transition induced by vacuum expectation values, and the instantons determine the vacuum structure of the theory, so they are crucial to get the correct VEVs. Could you ask a more specific question?

Comment: @ACuriousMind : I've added some specifications.